# Spring Boot: InvalidTypeIdException When Trying to Parse Json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to map POJO to a JSON response I get; however, I keep getting this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'order' as a subtype of `com.issbou.entity.OrdersList`: known type ids = [orders]
```

The Json response I get from the server and which I am trying to map to my POJO classes is:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 2039665099999,
      "email": "isx@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2039665066666,
      "email": "yzy@gmail.com"
    }
            ]
}
```

**Order**:Java Entity Class that represents a single order:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
public class Order {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private long id;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

}
```

**OrderList**:Java Entity Class that creates a lit of single orders:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@JsonTypeName("orders")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT ,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@Setter
@Getter
public class OrdersList {

    private List<Order> singleOrder;


}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class BasicAuth {

   public ResponseEntity<OrdersList> orderDetails (@RequestBody OrdersList order){

       String username = "username";
       String password = "password";
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);

       // request url
       String url = "https://test.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json";

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


       HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

       ResponseEntity<OrdersList> response = restTemplate.exchange(
               url, HttpMethod.GET, request, OrdersList.class);

       return response;
   }

}
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    BasicAuth basicAuth;

    @GetMapping("/lok")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersList> getBasicAut(OrdersList ordersList){

        return basicAuth.orderDetails(ordersList);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your OrdersList class doesn't contain a List. If you modify OrdersList so it looks like that:

```
import java.util.Collections.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@JsonTypeName("orders")
@Setter
@Getter
public class OrdersList {

    private List<Order> ordersList;
}
```

It should work.

And what I would rather do is accept a List of Order in the Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    BasicAuth basicAuth;

    @GetMapping("/lok")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Order>> getBasicAut(List<Order> ordersList){

        return basicAuth.orderDetails(ordersList);
    }
}
```

And then transfer Orders like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 2039665099999,
      "email": "isx@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2039665066666,
      "email": "yzy@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I do have OrderList taking Order as a list in fact and I get an InvalidTypeIdException.

Comment: Oh yes. You don't need the TypeInfo stuff. I edited my answer

Comment: No I do need the JsonTypeInfo to wrap up single orders in an Order object otherwise I receive a null value of SingleOrder Just like this: {
  "singleOrder": null
}

Comment: Did you try after making it a List? We use the same at work, and it works great

Comment: Oh wait, i'm sorry. You may need to add `orders:` before the Array in JSON

Comment: Yes ...That is why I have the JsonTypeName and JsonTypeInfo. They do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make the following changes to use the input given by you successfully:

1. Change `OrderList` to add a new field called `orders`.

   public class OrdersList {
       private List singleOrder;
       private List orders;
   }
2. Add `@PostMapping( "/lok" )` to your controller method to be able to POST the input
3. Add `@RequestBody` to the controller method input parameter

So the changed controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    BasicAuth basicAuth;

    @PostMapping( "/lok" )
    @GetMapping("/lok")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<OrdersList> getBasicAut( @RequestBody OrdersList ordersList){

        return basicAuth.orderDetails(ordersList);
    }
}
```

4. Had to comment out the following from `OrderList` class.

I think for wrapping up single orders, another way may have to be designed.

```
@JsonTypeName("orders")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT ,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
```